# Styling Polygons in 3D View as in 2D View in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, 3d-view

I have a sample set of polygons as shown in the picture below:

[image]

How can I keep the same symbology in 3D view instead of the grey metallic color ?

[image]

I am not sure how to achieve that.

[image]